# Error:Could not get unknown property 'libraryVariants' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension

Tags: android

> Error:Could not get unknown property 'libraryVariants' for object of
>   type com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension.

request help.

app->build.gradle:

[image]